# Drupal 7 Multi Image Upload Ubercart Marketplace

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'm trying to theme the front end ajax multi-image upload so the preview images are horizontal instead of in a rows vertically.  Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this?

I'm using the Multiupload Imagefield Widget module.

Comment: Can you show the page and/or final outcome your want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is add a left float to the row.

```
#edit-uc-product-image-und-table tr{float:left!important;}
```